# How do I split a string with complex delimiters using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I need to parse a string based on a regular expression and return a collection of strings.

The string I need to parse resembles the following:

```
"NM2RAJ/Fred MR(IR1234)/MISAMISS1BLACK/DROID MR 1BROWN/JACK(IECSL/HALDUW/13JUN12)"
```

From the above string I would like to return an array that contains the following strings from the original:

```
O/P=>

array temp=["NM","RAJ/Fred MR(IR1234)/MISAMISS","BLACK/DROID MR ","BROWN/JACK(IECSL/HALDUW/13JUN12)"]
```

The data should be partitioned on numbers which are not contained in parentheses.

Comment: i think , you need to split on 1 present in this `MISAMISS1BLACK` string also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use negative lookahead based regex.

```js
var s = "NM2RAJ/Fred MR(IR1234)/MISAMISS1BLACK/DROID MR 1BROWN/JACK(IECSL/HALDUW/13JUN12)"
alert(s.split(/\d+(?![^()]*\))/))
```

`\d+(?![^()]*\))` matches any number which isn't followed by, any character but not of `(` or `)`, zero or more times and a closing parenthesis `)` . So this matches all the number which was not present inside the paranthesis. I assumed that your parenthesis are properly closed.